# Is is possible that change HTML identifier tag in jsdom?

Tags: node.js, dom, jsdom

I'm going to use jsdom as text data processing rather than as HTML. To distinguish between HTML and text data, I want to use custom HTML identifier tag, such as `{{tag}} {{/tag}}` instead of `<tag> </tag>`.

Following node jsdom example outputs `print("foo bar")` which is enclosed by HTML tag `<python>`.

```
html=`
foo bar

<python>
print("foo bar")
</python>

foo bar

<python>print("foo bar")</python>

foo bar
` ; 

const dom = new JSDOM(html);

console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("python").textContent);
```

In this case, I want same result as above one from following one which uses custom HTML identifier tag not usual HTML identifier tag.

```
html=`
foo bar

{{python}}
print("foo bar")
{{/python}}

foo bar

{{python}}print("foo bar"){{/python}}

foo bar
` ; 

const dom = new JSDOM(html);

console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("python").textContent);
```

Is it possible and if so How do I implement that? thanks.